# How to access AWS Lambda callback results in Java

Tags: java, node.js, aws-lambda

I am calling an AWS Lambda function written in NodeJS which exports:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
```

The callback is passed the output of a SQL query:

```
new mssql.Request(conn).query(passedStatement,(err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        callback(err);
    } else {
        console.log("done");
        callback(null, result);
    }
});
```

I am calling this function from Java code:

```
InvokeRequest request = new InvokeRequest()
        .withFunctionName(lambdaFunctionName)
        .withPayload(jsonPayload)
        .withInvocationType(InvocationType.RequestResponse)
        .withLogType(LogType.Tail);

InvokeResult result = client.invoke(request);
```

The log result contains the message 'done' so I believe the code executed without errors. However, I can't see how to get the output from the SQL query. Assuming I pass `SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username = 'My User'`, how do I get user details in the Java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the result callback as JSON all that is required is:

```
new String(result.getPayload().array())
```